# jfreechart - remove spaces in chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using `JFreeChart`, and I want to remove the left and right spaces in my waterfall chart.

Here is what my chart looks like right now with the red squiggles to demonstrate the space I want to remove.

[image: WaterfallChart]

Any idea how to remove these spaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [`ChartFactory.createWaterfallChart()`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createWaterfallChart-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset-org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation-boolean-boolean-boolean-) instantiates a `CategoryAxis`, simply set the relevant margins:

```
CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setLowerMargin(0);
domainAxis.setUpperMargin(0);
```

Addendum: Note that negative values make the margin smaller, as illustrated [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/issues/388).

```
domainAxis.setLowerMargin(-0.05);
domainAxis.setUpperMargin(-0.05);
```